# Checking exit codes of two processes

Tags: c, fork, wait, exit-code

I have this code:

```
  pid_t pid1 = fork();

  if (pid1 == 0)
  {
    //do some stuff
    if (something)
        exit(0);
    else
        exit(1);
  }
  else if (pid1 == -1)
    printf("error\n");

  pid_t pid2 = fork();

  if (pid2 == 0)
  {
    //do some stuff
    if (something)
        exit(0);
    else
        exit(1);
  }
  else if (pid2 == -1)
    printf("error\n");

//here I want to check both exit codes
```

The child processes will run in parallel. What I need is to check both exit codes whether they're `1` or `0`. I thought I could use something like this:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
while( (pid = wait(&status)) > 0)
   printf("%d exit code: %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
```

I am new to parallel programming so I am not sure if this is a correct solution. Isn't there possibility that one of the child processes exits before parent process reaches cycle so it won't get exit code?

Comment: And what is the problem you have with your code? What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one or both of the child processes exit before the parent first calls `wait()`, then the OS will hold the exit code and/or reason for termination until the parent reaches the `wait()`.  This is exactly what a "zombie process" is.

Answer (score 2):

If a process exits before the parent process reaches `wait()`, it will become a `defunct` process (or `zombie` process). This is OK, because if a `wait` function is called later, it will get that exit code and the zombie process will be terminated successfully.

Instead of using `wait()` which will just wait for any process, you can use `waitpid()` to wait for a specific process, as determined by its specific `PID`, since you have to wait for two processes.

> `pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);`
>
> The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until
>   one of its children terminates. The call wait(&status) is equivalent
>   to:
>
> `waitpid(-1, &status, 0);`
>
> The waitpid() system call suspends execution of the calling process
>   until a child specified by pid argument has changed state. By default,
>   waitpid() waits only for terminated children, but this behavior is
>   modifiable via the options argument, as described below.
>   The value of pid can be:
>
> `< -1`
>
> meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to
>   the absolute value of pid.
>
> `-1`
>
> meaning wait for any child process.
>
> `0`
>
> meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to
>   that of the calling process.
>
> `> 0`
>
> meaning wait for the child whose process ID is equal to the value of
>   pid.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

`wait()` will block until one of the two processes ends, and return info about that process.  You can either call `wait()` until there are no more children, or use `waitpid` to get info about the specific PIDs.

So to answer your question -- your code looks fine.  `wait()` takes care of the race condition for you, as it blocks execution until one of the children exits (or is stopped by another means).